# Video Progressively Lags Behind Audio

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

I am trying to use the Stream feature in VLC Media Player to download a video from the internet. The video plays just fine when viewed online, and there is no problem with it whatsoever, but when I use VLC to download the video, there is an issue where as the video progress, it starts to lag behind the audio. As you get closer to the end of the video, the lag worsens. Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it? Here are the settings I am using for downloading the video.

[image: VLC Stream Settings]
[image: VLC Stream Settings]
[image: VLC Stream Settings]
[image: VLC Stream Settings]
[image: VLC Stream Settings]

I do not know if this information is helpful, but the address of the video which I am trying to download uses the 'm3u8' file extension.

`http://www.example.com/video.m3u8`

If it is significant, here is the content of the `m3u8` file when opened with NotePad++.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.005,
n_0_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:5.005,
n_1_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_2_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_3_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_4_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_5_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_6_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_7_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_8_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_9_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_10_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_11_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_12_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_13_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_14_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_15_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_16_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_17_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_18_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_19_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_20_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_21_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_22_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_23_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_24_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_25_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_26_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_27_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_28_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_29_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_30_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_31_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_32_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_33_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_34_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_35_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_36_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_37_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_38_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_39_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_40_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_41_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_42_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_43_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_44_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_45_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_46_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_47_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_48_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_49_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_50_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_51_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_52_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_53_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_54_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_55_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_56_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_57_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_58_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_59_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_60_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_61_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_62_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_63_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_64_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_65_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_66_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_67_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_68_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_69_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_70_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_71_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_72_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_73_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_74_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_75_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_76_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_77_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_78_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_79_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_80_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_81_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_82_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_83_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_84_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_85_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_86_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_87_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_88_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_89_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_90_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_91_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_92_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_93_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_94_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_95_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_96_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_97_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_98_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_99_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_100_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_101_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_102_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_103_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_104_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_105_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_106_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_107_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_108_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_109_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_110_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_111_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_112_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_113_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_114_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_115_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_116_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_117_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_118_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_119_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_120_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_121_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_122_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_123_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_124_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_125_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_126_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_127_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_128_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_129_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_130_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_131_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_132_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_133_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_134_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_135_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_136_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_137_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_138_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_139_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_140_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_141_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_142_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_143_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_144_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_145_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_146_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_147_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_148_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_149_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_150_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_151_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_152_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_153_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_154_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_155_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_156_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_157_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_158_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_159_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_160_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_161_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_162_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_163_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_164_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_165_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_166_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_167_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_168_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_169_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_170_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_171_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_172_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_173_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_174_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_175_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_176_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_177_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_178_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_179_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_180_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_181_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_182_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_183_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_184_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_185_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_186_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_187_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_188_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_189_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_190_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_191_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_192_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_193_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_194_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_195_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_196_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_197_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_198_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_199_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_200_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_201_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_202_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_203_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_204_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_205_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_206_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_207_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_208_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_209_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_210_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_211_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_212_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_213_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_214_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_215_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_216_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_217_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_218_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_219_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_220_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_221_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_222_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_223_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_224_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_225_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_226_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_227_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_228_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_229_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_230_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_231_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_232_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_233_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_234_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_235_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_236_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_237_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_238_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_239_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_240_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_241_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_242_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_243_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_244_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_245_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_246_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_247_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_248_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_249_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_250_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_251_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_252_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_253_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_254_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_255_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_256_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_257_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_258_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_259_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_260_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_261_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_262_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_263_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_264_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_265_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_266_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_267_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_268_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_269_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_270_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_271_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_272_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_273_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_274_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_275_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_276_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_277_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_278_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_279_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_280_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_281_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_282_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_283_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_284_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_285_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_286_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_287_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_288_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_289_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_290_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_291_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_292_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_293_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_294_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_295_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_296_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_297_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_298_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_299_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_300_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_301_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_302_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_303_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_304_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_305_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_306_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_307_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_308_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_309_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_310_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_311_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_312_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_313_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_314_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_315_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_316_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_317_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_318_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_319_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_320_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_321_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_322_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_323_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_324_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_325_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_326_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_327_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_328_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_329_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_330_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_331_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_332_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_333_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_334_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_335_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_336_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_337_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_338_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_339_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_340_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_341_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_342_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_343_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_344_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_345_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_346_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_347_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_348_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_349_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_350_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_351_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_352_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_353_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_354_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_355_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_356_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_357_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_358_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_359_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_360_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_361_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_362_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_363_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_364_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_365_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_366_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_367_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_368_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_369_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_370_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_371_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_372_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_373_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_374_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_375_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_376_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_377_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_378_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_379_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_380_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_381_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_382_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_383_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_384_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_385_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_386_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_387_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_388_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_389_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_390_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_391_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_392_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_393_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_394_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_395_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_396_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_397_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_398_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_399_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_400_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_401_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_402_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_403_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_404_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_405_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_406_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:7.507,
n_407_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXTINF:5.555,
n_408_0_0.ts?nimblesessionid=2035851
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Here is the codec information from the resulting video after it is fully downloaded.

[image: Codec Informaton]

Here are the statistics according to VLC. These statistics were taken from within the first 30 seconds of the video.

[image: Statistics Information]

What is the issue that I am having, and how can I resolve it? If more information is required, please feel free to ask me for it.

Comment: When you were not keeping original audio file, does the sample rate match that which was being streamed?  converting a sample rate can have this (bad audio sync) happen easily in other stuff even if re-sampling should not be changing time.  Because of that i try and keep original sample rates in all possible conditions, even when transcoding the audio.

Comment: @Psycogeek As far as I am aware, the `Keep original audio track` option streams the audio and does not alter it at all, so everything should be the same about the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have been unable to find a direct solution to the problem when streaming, I have found a workaround that fixes the issue on streamed videos that have the problem. To resolve the issue, use VLC Media Player to stream the video to an MP4 file. When starting the stream, make sure that on the `Transcoding Options` page, you click the wrench and check the `Video codec` and `Audio codec` tabs. Make sure that in each respective tab, the `Keep original video track` and `Keep original audio track` options are checked.

After the video is done streaming, use an audio converter of your choice to create an MP3 file. In my case, I used `VSDC Free Audio Converter` to convert the MP4 file to an MP3 file, resulting the end file containing only the audio from the streamed file. Then, use a video editor to mute the sound from the video and overlay the MP3 file on top of the video. The video editor that I used was `AVS Video Editor`, although this trick should work for other timeline-based video editing software as well.

I do not know why this trick works, but it seems to resolve the issue. If anyone does know, why, please explain it.